# @atlaskit/editor-core bundle size problem with Webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, babel-loader, atlaskit

I'm trying to use @atlaskit/editor-core. It works good but it outputs a 15+mb vendor.js file. I have prepared [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/denizoguz/AtlaskitMediaCoreBundleSizeProblem) to demonstrate this problem. I have two questions:

- Are my babel.config.js and webpack.common.js files are set up correctly for optimizing bundle size?
- Why Webpack is creating an additional 3rd file with name "@atlaskit-internal_media-viewer-pdf-viewer-bundle.min"? I'm not specifying this file in chunks section or in entry points. In my actual project it is creating more than 30 small files like this although I don't specify them.

Comment: Hi. Any updates on this?

Comment: I have seen other people complaining about bundle size of atlaskit editor and usually the response is "it is large, this is normal".

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: meanwhile draft.js is < 2MB...